# Grand Central Dispatch when program enter suspended mode

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Let's assume that I have a GDC thread running when the app goes inti suspended mode. What will happen? Will the tread stop or continue running? Or do I have to stop it myself, in that case how is this done?

Thankful for advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Background State & NSThread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/233046#233046)

The system automatically suspends all threads include GCD threads.